# Derivation for geometric series / probability distribution function

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

$X$ follows a geometric distribution.

Where do this derivation come from?

$$P(X \geq 14) = 1-P(X\leq14-1) = 1- \sum_{x=1}^{14-1}(1-p)^{x-1}p=1-p\frac{1-(1-p)^{14-1}}{1-(1-p)} = (1-p)^{14-1}$$

I mean, how does it go from the third to the fourth expression? I believe it has something to do with the geometric series but couldn't quite get the passage. And is the $14-1$ really important or could one just write $13$?

Comment: Your third expression is not correct. It should be $1-\sum_{x=1}^{13}(1-p)^{x-1}p$

Comment: There is a quicker route to $P(X \geq 14) = (1-p)^{14-1}$: it says the first success happening on the $14$th attempt or later is the equivalent to none of the  initial $14-1=13$ attempts being successes

Comment: Any further questions?

Answer (score 1):

The expression $X\leq 14-1$ comes from the fact that $X$ is a $\underline{\textrm{discrete}}$ random variable. At a discrete random variable we have $P(X\geq x)=1-P(X\leq x-1)$. But to calculate the sum it is sufficient to use/write $13$.

At first I would make an index shift: $x-1=k$

$$\sum_{x=1}^{13}(1-p)^{x-1}p=\sum_{k=0}^{12}(1-p)^{k}p=p\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{12}(1-p)^{k}$$

Next you use  indeed the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series:  $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}r^{k}=\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$

$$=p\cdot \frac{(1-p)^{13}-1}{1-p-1}$$

The denominator is $-p$. So we can cancel $p$ and it remains the factor $(-1)$. So the numerator is multiplied by $(-1)$

$$=1-(1-p)^{13}$$